# htaccess mod_rewrite good in IE, but downloads web page in other browsers (Chrome, Firefox)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to modify an .htaccess file so that file extensions are omitted-- mainly .html  It seems to be working fine in IE written like this:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
AddType text/html .html

But in Chrome or Firefox (haven't tried any others) the web page immediately downloads instead of displays without the extension.

I have never modified this file before-- I got the above Rewrite lines from another site but I cannot seem to find any solution to prevent the files from downloading in those browsers. This site is hosted on Amazon Web Services.

Thanks

Comment: IE has the nasty habit of ignoring the Content-Type header, and "guesses" what a resource might be - which has already lead to security problems in the past. // AddType should work on the basis of the actual physical filename, so I don't immediately see why this wouldn't work. But you can also specify the MIME type via the [`T` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_t) of the RewriteRule - so give that a try, and see if you get a different result.

Comment: do yuou mean add a line like this but to replace html with null? RewriteRule html - [T=xxx/xxx]  Not sure how that would be written

Comment: Replace what with null where ...? I said try to use the RewriteRule flag to set the content type, _instead of_ AddType

Comment: OK replace it, but i'm just not sure how to write the line. This is an example on the linked page: RewriteRule IMG - [T=image/jpg]      so change IMG to HTML then T=NULL or something?

Comment: Do you want it to send `Content-Type: NULL` ...? No, you want `text/html`.

Comment: The first cond is redundant, unless you might have files that are named exactly `.html`. I'd drop it.